# Calculate the end of the previous quarter

Tags: python

I'm looking for an elegant and pythonic way to get the date of the end of the previous quarter.

Something like this:

```
def previous_quarter(reference_date):
   ...


>>> previous_quarter(datetime.date(2013, 5, 31))
datetime.date(2013, 3, 31)

>>> previous_quarter(datetime.date(2013, 2, 1))
datetime.date(2012, 12, 31)

>>> previous_quarter(datetime.date(2013, 3, 31))
datetime.date(2012, 12, 31)

>>> previous_quarter(datetime.date(2013, 11, 1))
datetime.date(2013, 9, 30)
```

**Edit: Have I tried anything?**

Yes, this seems to work:

```
def previous_quarter(ref_date):
    current_date = ref_date - timedelta(days=1)
    while current_date.month % 3:
        current_date -= timedelta(days=1)
    return current_date
```

But it seems unnecessarily iterative.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Looking at my solution it clearly won't work if `ref_date.month` is divisible by 3...

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can do it the "hard way" by just looking at the month you receive:

```
def previous_quarter(ref):
    if ref.month < 4:
        return datetime.date(ref.year - 1, 12, 31)
    elif ref.month < 7:
        return datetime.date(ref.year, 3, 31)
    elif ref.month < 10:
        return datetime.date(ref.year, 6, 30)
    return datetime.date(ref.year, 9, 30)
```

Comment: I like it- clean, simple, and effective.

Answer (score 5):

Using [dateutil](http://niemeyer.net/python-dateutil):

```
import datetime as DT
import dateutil.rrule as rrule

def previous_quarter(date):
    date = DT.datetime(date.year, date.month, date.day)
    rr = rrule.rrule(
        rrule.DAILY,
        bymonth=(3,6,9,12),    # the month must be one of these
        bymonthday=-1,         # the day has to be the last of the month
        dtstart = date-DT.timedelta(days=100))
    result = rr.before(date, inc=False)  # inc=False ensures result < date
    return result.date()

print(previous_quarter(DT.date(2013, 5, 31)))
# 2013-03-31
print(previous_quarter(DT.date(2013, 2, 1)))
# 2012-12-31
print(previous_quarter(DT.date(2013, 3, 31)))
# 2012-12-31
print(previous_quarter(DT.date(2013, 11, 1)))
# 2013-09-30
```

Answer (score 2):

Exploit the data pattern involved and turn the problem into a table-lookup - your classic [space-time tradeff](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space-time_tradeoff):

```
from datetime import date

PQTBL = (((12,31,-1),)*3 + ((3,31,0),)*3 + ((6,30,0),)*3 + ((9,30,0),)*3)

def previous_quarter(ref):
    entry = PQTBL[ref.month-1]
    return date(ref.year+entry[2], entry[0], entry[1])
```

Comment: should be: `return date(ref.year+entry[2], entry[0], entry[1])`  (sign should be changed)

Comment: @Gerrat: Fixed. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Find the first day and month of the quarter, then use `relativedelta` to subtract a day.

```py
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
def previous_quarter(ref):
    first_month_of_quarter = ((ref.month - 1) // 3) * 3 + 1
    return ref.replace(month=first_month_of_quarter, day=1) - relativedelta(days=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

It's almost certain you would be happier using pandas (a python library), it has many functions for "business time" data.

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/timeseries.html

Comment: It's not an unreasonable suggestion, but perhaps you'd like to show an example?

Answer (score 1):

Reworked [Justin Ethier's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/101258/justin-ethier) code for a "next quarter" version. Also added timezone via pytz and strftime formatting. @justin-ethier

```py
import pytz
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import datetime as dt

def nextQuarter():
    ref = datetime.now(pytz.timezone('America/New_York'))
    if ref.month < 4:
        next = dt.datetime(ref.year, 3, 31, 23, 59, 59).strftime('%m-%d-%Y %H:%M:%S')
    elif ref.month < 7:
        next = dt.datetime(ref.year, 6, 30, 23, 59, 59).strftime('%m-%d-%Y %H:%M:%S')
    elif ref.month < 10:
        next = dt.datetime(ref.year, 9, 30, 23, 59, 59).strftime('%m-%d-%Y %H:%M:%S')
    else:
        next = dt.datetime(ref.year + 1, 12, 31, 23, 59, 59).strftime('%m-%d-%Y %H:%M:%S')
    return next
next = nextQuarter()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import datetime
def previous_quarter(ref):
    quarter = (ref.month - 1) // 3
    prev_quarter = (quarter - 1) % 4
    return datetime.datetime(ref.year if quarter>0 else ref.year-1, prev_quarter*3+1, 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution using only python's [datetime](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html) library -

```
import datetime

def get_quarter_end(dt):
     '''
         given a datetime object, find the end of the quarter
     '''
     quarter_of_month = int((dt.month-1)/3 + 1)
     #======================================================
     # find the first day of the next quarter
     #======================================================
     # if in last quarter then go to the next year
     year = dt.year + 1 if quarter_of_month==4 else dt.year
     # if in last quarter then month is january (or 1)
     month = 1 if quarter_of_month==4 else (quarter_of_month*3) + 1

     first_of_next_quarter = datetime.datetime(year  = year, 
                                               month = month,
                                               day   = 1
                                              )
     # last day of quarter for dt will be minus 1 day of first of next quarter
     quarter_end_dt = first_of_next_quarter - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
     return quarter_end_dt

if __name__=='__main__':
    dt = datetime.datetime.strptime('2016-07-15', '%Y-%m-%d')
    target_dt = get_quarter_end(dt)
```

Comment: Is this Python 2 or 3? I ask because I'm wondering if you meant `int((dt.month-1)/3 + 1)` or `int((dt.month-1)//3 + 1)`. NVM: it works in Python 3 just fine. But you could do `quarter_of_month = (dt.month-1)//3+1`, to be more concise.

Answer (score 0):

and if you want to retreive the last fours quarter you can do this

```
    if ref.month < 4:
        list1 = [datetime.date(ref.year - 1, 12, 31),
                            datetime.date(ref.year - 1, 9, 30),
                            datetime.date(ref.year - 1, 6, 30),
                            datetime.date(ref.year - 1, 3, 31)]

        list1 = [i.strftime('%Y%m%d') for i in list1]

        return list1

    elif ref.month < 7:
        return [datetime.date(ref.year, 3, 31),
                datetime.date(ref.year - 1, 12, 31),
                datetime.date(ref.year - 1, 9, 30),
                datetime.date(ref.year - 1, 6, 30)]
    elif ref.month < 10:
        return [datetime.date(ref.year, 6, 30),
                datetime.date(ref.year, 3, 31),
                datetime.date(ref.year - 1, 12, 31),
                datetime.date(ref.year - 1, 9, 30)]

    return [datetime.date(ref.year, 9, 30),
            datetime.date(ref.year, 6, 30),
            datetime.date(ref.year, 3, 30),
            datetime.date(ref.year - 1, 12, 31)]
```